# Custom UITableView Which is like ASP.Net Grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to develop iPad application and i need a Custom UITableView which is similar to asp.net grid.

I can't use the default UITableView because i need more than one column and which replicates dynamically by the columns of dataset.

I need something like that:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/biswapinky/developing-a-multi-select-Asp-Net-gridview-using-jquery/Images/multi_select_gridview.png

I was searched for making CustomUITableCell's but i cannot find any example like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- just use a single tableview with a customcell showing all the values in labels and use it
  [i prefer this]

OR

- Create a subclass of UITableView
- Make it all the design as in the required
- Initialize and add as subviews[ in a loop specifying the frame  width and orgin x in frame ]to a view as required inputs

Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)  and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Try UICollectionView, they are new in iOS6, have similar usage to TableViews (datasource, delegate etc..) but are more flexible and have a grid arrangement option provided.